# Android Studio: exchange data between classes

Tags: java, android

I would like to learn how to exchange data between classes(in Android Studio).
For that purpose I have created three Java classes:

1) GraficActivity.java:

```
public class GraficActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testview);
        //not working:      iv.update(100,100);
        DataHolder.setData(100, 100);
    }
}
```

2) DrawingView.java:

```
public class DrawingView extends ImageView {
    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    private int X=200;
    private int Y=200;
    //not working:  X = DataHolder.getX();
    //not working:  Y = DataHolder.getY();
    public void update(int dataX, int dataY) {
        X=dataX;
        Y=dataY;
        this.invalidate();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint pinsel = new Paint();
        pinsel.setColor(Color.rgb(64, 64, 255));
        pinsel.setStrokeWidth(5);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, X, Y, pinsel);
    }
}
```

3) DataHolder.java:

```
public class DataHolder {
    private static int X;
    private static int Y;
    public static int getX() {return X;}
    public static int getY() {return Y;}
    public static void setData(int dataX, int dataY) {X = dataX; Y=dataY;}
}
```

I included `DrawingView` in the layout (together with other elements) with the following code in main.xml:

```
<de.carpelibrum.grafik.DrawingView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp" 
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/testview" />
```

The app works in principle, but I could not find a way to transfer data from `GraficActivity` to `DrawingView`.

I tried two methods(as indicated in the code above):

1. Via a separate `DataHolder` as global variable
2. With the function `update(int, int)` in `DrawingView`.

Finally, I will need to transfer not only two integers, but the content of an array: `int data[][];`.

How to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Cheers,
Kyriakos.

Answer (score 1):

`ImageView` does not have a method `update(int, int)`. You should cast the View associated with the id `R.id.testView` to your type `DrawingView`. Then `update(int, int)` should become available at compile-time:

```
DrawingView iv = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.testview);
```

Also, consider that your `DataHolder` and `DrawingView` are *both* storing position data. Pick one. If the data is specific to an *instance* of `DrawingView`, then you don't need `DataHolder`.

Answer (score 0):

perfect! Thank you.

Regarding the database, I put it in "GraficActivity", sratched "DataHolder", and used a pointer as parameter in the "update" function:

in "GraficActivity":

```
    private int data[][]=new int[10][10];
data[0][0] = 200;    
data[0][1] = 100;
iv.update(data);
```

in "DrawingView":

```
    public void update(int[][] dataXY) {
    X=dataXY[0][0];
    Y=dataXY[0][1];
    this.invalidate();
}
```

Now this is a good working basis.

Cheers,
Kyriakos.